# bash rename files with prefix serial number

Tags: bash

I have loads of files in a folder. I want to do two things:

1. prefix them with xxx three digit serial numbers - ascending: 001 002 and so on
2. remove the prefix from their names, so 001a.xyz = a.xyz

I intend to do this using a simple bash script. What's the most elegant and simple to understand way to do this?

**edit**

the files are on a removable device, and I cannot seem to set chmod +X on the script on the device. So how do I run a script from my home directory which will change the files in another directory?

Comment: Is this to say you want _two_ scripts, one which adds prefixes, and another which removes them?

Comment: Wait what? You want to add a prefix and then remove the prefix?  And what if you have 001a.xyz as well as 002a.xyz - if the prefix is removed one will be overwritten.

Comment: "Elegant and simple to understand", as a rule, are bad things to focus on in bash -- bash is a language that's full of pitfalls; if you want to write robust code, you focus first on _correct_; it's much too easy to come up with something intuitively understandable but prone to subtle bugs. If you want a language where correct code and elegant code are one and the same, I suggest Python, or a well-thought-out LISP.

Comment: yes, two scripts! the overwrite condition wont be true, that's guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

To add prefixes:

```
counter=1
for f in *; do
  printf -v prefix_str '%03d' "$((counter++))"
  mv "$f" "${prefix_str}$f"
done
```

To remove prefixes (caution -- this may overwrite if you have two files with the same suffix but different prefixes):

```
for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do
  mv "$f" "${f:3}"
done
```

Use `mv -n` to avoid overwriting when two files have the same suffix.

Comment: Good solution. One minor correction. **To add prefix** solution has no counter increment and will start with 000.

Comment: that can be easily changed by setting counter=1 for start value

Comment: @robmayhoff Thanks for the edit -- that said, in this case, I think putting the counter increment into a math context (`$((counter++))`) is a terser approach.

Comment: Terser, but note that `help let` provides a useful result while `help ((` or `help $((` does not.

Comment: @robmayoff It's a reasonable expectation that someone who's going to be using a language know its syntax; otherwise we live in a world of lowest-common-denominator code. (Particularly true in the case of `$((`, which is standardized as part of the POSIX sh specification -- unlike the bare `((` form, which is a bash extension).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1
for file in *; do
  if [[ $file =~ [0-9][0-9][0-9].* ]]; then
    sfile="${file:3}"
    new=$(printf "%03d" ${count}) 
    mv "$file" "${new}${sfile}"
    ((count++))
  else
    new=$(printf "%03d" ${count})
    mv "$file" "${new}${file}"
    ((count++))
  fi
done
```

What this script does is, checks for a given file in the current directory. If the file has a prefix already it will remove it and assign a new sequential prefix. If the file has no prefix it will add a sequential prefix to it.

The end result should be, all the files in your current directory (some with and some without prefixes) will have a new sequential prefixes.